# Need advice with typescript and createAsyncThunk

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am learning to create slices to handle all of my state and async actions. I am copying [the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) in trying to do this but I am getting an error with typescript.

My Code:

```
export const fetchTrackData = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/fetchAllTracksData",
  async (user: any, data: any, spotifyToken: any, thunkApi: any) => {
    try {
      if (!spotifyToken)
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue({
          type: CustomError.NO_SPOTIFY_TOKEN,
        });
      const response = await fetchSpotifyData(user, data, spotifyToken);
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      thunkApi.rejectWithValue({
        type: CustomError.ERROR_FETCHING_SPOTIFY_DATA,
        reason: err.response,
      });
    }
  }
);
```

The Error:

```
Argument of type '(user: any, data: any, spotifyToken: any, thunkApi: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<any, void, {}>'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: try to add a return in your catch block

Comment: Didn't change anything @misha1109

Comment: you right sorry for misleading you. what about my answer?:)

Answer (score 2):

I think the signature of your callback (payloadCreator) is not correct,
In the documentation, it states two values are passed to the function.

'The payloadCreator function will be called with two arguments:'

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: Yup this is it.  They need to be combining their first three arguments into a single object with three properties.